# FCM Acks receiving real world scenario Test - (after deploying android app in 5 Million Devices )

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-device-farm

**Idea of this project :**

- Create a portal where anyone can create custom advertisement and push
  it to the all the registered devices.(Supports only Android for now.)
- Registered devices are the one which has android app installed in it.

**Implementation:**

1. **For push notifications**: Firebase Cloud Messaging is used.
2. **Android App**: simple app with FCM integrated into it.
3. **Web UI**: where a client can submit ad job.
4. **server**: interacts with FCM to send notification in batches

When client submits ad job, using device registered tokens were sending ads.

Once FCM sends notification to devices, **"Acknowledge delivered"** and **"Acknowledge Clicked"** are received from registered devices.

**Major Goal:**

- I wanted to see how my server responds/handles when million or more
  acknowledgements received from the all devices.

So for this purpose, i explored the below services which provides us virtual and physical devices online

1. [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/)
2. [Xamarin test cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud)
3. [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/test-lab/)
4. private cloud where millions of AVDs can be running. [Dint research much on this part]

But for million android devices, first three are charging hefty.

for time-being, i have done simulation to test this scenario.
but wanted to test in real world scenario?
How can it be done?

Thanks for answering guys.

Comment: You would want to mock the "client" by simulating the content that the device sends to in order to load test your functional behavior and measure performance, actual spin up AVD or using physical devices is impractical.  There are ***many*** toolsets that can help you explore/measure your scalability, such as JMeter....

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover
You mean to say there is no such services provided by any company and doing it on own is also not feasible. ?

Comment: Spinning up a "million android devices" is just impractial at many levels, none of services you listed have anywhere near that number of many devices, a thousand or so, but not millions. It is also impractical to consider doing the same for AVDs, the number of clients running **just** `adb` for AVD device control would be impractical. When performing load testing/scalability ***at scale*** it is typically done on the protocol level, you need to measure how your service(s) perform as input increases and not just how you scale vertically but also horizontally.

Comment: Ok thanks @SushiHangover